# Row data into Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this list of student and i want to make the Date record as the column

[image]

I want the result to be like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries demand that you know the columns to select beforehand. If you know exactly which dates to expect, then you can select them as columns using Pivot or conditional aggregation:

```
select
  max(case when date = {d '2015-08-01'} then student_id end) as date20150801,
  max(case when date = {d '2015-08-02'} then student_id end) as date20150802,
  ...
from mytable
group by student_id;
```

Usually, however, you would simply select the data as rows with SQL and care about the presentation as columns in a grid with your GUI language (Java, C#, PHP, whatever).